# Why does the continuous sum of the series (1/2^x) yield a smaller result than the discrete sum?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

The sum of the discrete series comes to be $1$:
$$S = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{x}}$$
$$S = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+...$$
$$S = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+...\right)$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{S}{2}$$
$$S=1$$

However, the sum of the similar continuous series comes out to be $0.721347520444$:
$$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{x}}dx$$
Taking $2^{-x}=t$, i.e., $x=1 => t=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\infty => t=0$:
$$-x=\log_{2}x$$
Differentiating with respect to x on both sides, we get:
$$dx=\frac{-1}{t\ln2}dt$$
Putting all this back into the original equation, we get:
$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}t\cdot\frac{-1}{t\ln2}dt$$
$$=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}\frac{-1}{\ln2}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\ln2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}-1dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{\ln2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$$
$$ =\frac{1}{2\ln2}$$
$$=0.721347520444$$

How is $I < S$, despite $I$ already having the values contained in $S$, and infinitely more?

---

Edit: Fixed typo

Comment: why does a cone have less volume than a cylinder with the same base and height?

Comment: I don't quite get the juxtaposition, a cone does not contain the entire cylinder (and then some) inside of it.

Comment: For every strictly decreasing positive continuous function $f$ you have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) > \int_1^\infty f(x) \,dx$, simply because $f(n) > \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\, dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An image of the things you're trying to compare.

[image]

Note that the blue lines are always above the curve.

The trick with summation vs integration is *always* that the summation assumes a certain width; integration takes a width that limits to 0.

Comment: That does clear it up for me. I did not think about the width of the discrete values, and only thought of them as vertical lines on the continuous graph.

Answer (score 7):

The series you give is an upper Riemann sum for the integral, and hence is an overestimate.

Comment: Perfect answer it’s litteraly that

Comment: It feels like all of these don't make the slightest bit of sense. The sum $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$ itself gives a value that is greater than the integral sum $0.75\ >\ 0.7213...$. The function does not yield any negative values as well, so how does this make sense?

Comment: @elementalneil Yes: The first two terms of the sum have enough extra to be greater than the entire integral. Break up the integral over unit subintervals (1 to 2; 2 to 3; etc.). On each subinterval, the value of the integral is half that of the previous interval; with a start value of $\frac{1}{4\ln 2} \approx .3607$. The terms of the  series also decrease by a factor of one-half, but terms of the series start at $.5$.  The series has enough extra (vs. the integral) over the first two terms, so the value of the first two terms of the series already exceeds the value of the entire integral.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} 2^{-x}dx = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{i}^{i+1} 2^{-x}dx$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{2} 2^{-i}2^{-x}dx
=  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 2^{-i}\int_{1}^{2} 2^{-x}dx$$

So now it remains to show that $\int_{1}^{2} 2^{-x}dx$ is strictly less than $2^{-1}$. Note however that as $2^{-x}$ is a continous function that is no larger than $\frac{1}{2}=2^{-1}$ for all $x \in (1,2]$, and is as small as $\frac{1}{4}$ on the interval $(1,2]$ [namely at $x=2$], it follows that
$$\int_{1}^{2} 2^{-x}dx \ < \ \int_1^2 2^{-1}dx \ = \ 2^{-1} \times (2-1) \ = \ 2^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}2^{-m}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int_m^{m+1}2^{-m}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int_m^{m+1}2^{-\lfloor{x}\rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^{\infty}2^{-\lfloor{x}\rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_1^{\infty}2^{\lceil-x\rceil}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Since $\lceil-x\rceil\gt-x,$ it follows that $$2^{\lceil-x\rceil}\gt2^{-x},$$ and thus, $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}2^{-m}=\int_1^{\infty}2^{\lceil-x\rceil}\,\mathrm{d}x\gt\int_1^{\infty}2^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ On the note that the integral includes the terms of the series already as part of the "continuous sum," as you call it, you are correct, but what you are ignoring is that those terms are being multiplied by quantities close to $0,$ and the same is true for all other "terms" that are part of this "continuous sum." Recall that the Riemann integral is the limit of a net of Riemann sums that look like $$\sum_{m=0}^n2^{-t_m}\Delta{x_m},$$ where $\Delta{x_m}\to0.$